# what's the difference between binding ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and to a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, listview, itemssource, collectionviewsource

I know CollectionViewSource support grouping and sorting, except this, is there any other difference between binding ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and to a CollectionViewSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the underlying [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in addition to grouping, sorting, filtering, maintains [CurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that comes handy while setting from ViewModel.

Comment: It means we'd better always use CollectionViewSource instead of binding to an ObseravableCollection directly?

Comment: It depends. I tend to use `CollectionViewSource` whenever simple grouping/filtering/current item is required. For all other, Usually I go with ObservableCollection. This is merely my preference (and not a stardard/guideline)